# Improve openvpn bandwidth Debian 7

Tags: vpn, performance

I configured openvpn on a dedicated server. Things are working fine but the bandwidth is not as high as it should be given the network specifications :

The dedicated server has 250Mbps DL speed and 150Mbps UP speed
My home internet has 100Mbps DL speed and 7Mbps UP speed
So the link between the two is theoretically maxing at 10MiB/s.
Would like to setup the maximum bandwidth for the tunnel.

Problem is the tunnel only reaches 1MiB/s. Is there a way to improve the bandwidth within the tunnel?

Here's my config :

- The dedicated server is running Debian Squeeze

  - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU
  - E3-1225 V2 @ 3.20GHz , 32 RAM
  - OpenVPN is version 2.1.3-2 (from repositories)
- My client is Dell poweredge 830 Intel E7230, 8 Ram . running Debian 7 64 bit and OpenVPN

server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS xxx.186.33.99"
push "dhcp-option DNS 127.0.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

client.conf

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.195.99 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client1.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client1.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: How exactly are you testing your bandwidth?  An iperf test between the VPN server and client would probably be the most useful.  Ideally you should do a bidirectional test between the server and client directly across the Internet, and then across the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Thank, testing my bandwidth by simply download 1 MB file and check the speed /s , on windows client simply by checking speedtest.net

Comment: I strongly suggest you test with iperf then.  It will be a far more useful test since it will directly measure the link link between you and the server.

Comment: thanks iperf  test done on tcp connection and result :49.1 MB download speed.

Answer (score 0):

> The dedicated server has 250Mbps DL speed and 150Mbps UP speed My home
>   internet has 100Mbps DL speed and 7Mbps UP speed So the link between
>   the two is theoretically maxing at 10MiB/s.

Well, your circuit at work and your circuit at home are only a small piece of the whole system. When you purchase a circuit that will provide X Mbps download or X Mbps upload, those are **theoretical maximum** values. You are not guaranteed to be able to download or upload at X Mbps from anywhere on the internet. When traffic leaves your house through the OpenVPN tunnel, it likely traverses 10-20 more routers on its way to your office, any of which could have interfaces that are running at their maximum speed. Consumer ISPs are especially guilty of under-provisioning their network gear.

tl;dr: There are many pieces of network gear between your home and your office, any of which could be slowing things down.

Comment: thanks for reply, but internet speed on server 250MB and at client is 100 MB , its not make sense to drop the speed on vpn tunnel to 10 MB download and on windows client even worth 10 MB download and only 5 MB download !!! , is there is any configuration to be added.